# Pass values of <a> elements from client side to a server side function

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script

I have a sidebar with checkboxes (`<input>`) and corresponding names (`<a>`).

**I can't get values from `<a>` tags.**

I need when user ticks checkboxes and presses the button **to get values of corresponding names** and **pass the names to a backend function to get calendars for that names** from sheet data.

I wrote this code and logged the data (logged the names param at the very beginning of a backend function) and there were correct names in the log at first.

But then without changes to the code I stopped receiving any logs, so I assumed the backend function stopped being called.

What's wrong with my code?

```
//get button by id, on click run function
document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click", requestCheckedCalendars)
```

The client-side functions:

```js
//getting checked checkboxes and names
function getCheckedNames() {

  //getting all checkboxes
  var allCheckboxes = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("filled-in"));

  //getting all <a> tag elements as a native Array.
  var names = Array.from(document.getElementsByTagName("a"));
  
  var namesArr = []

  for (var i = 1; i < allCheckboxes.length; i++) {
  
      //checked/unchecked property of a checkbox
      var check = allCheckboxes[i].checked
      
      //if checked
      if (check === true) {
      
      //shift to get corresponding names  
      var j = i + 1
     
      //getting a name value
      var name = names[j].firstChild.nodeValue;
      
      //pushing a name to the array
      namesArr.push(name)  
      }
      }
  
  return namesArr
  }


//getting calendars for chosen names from backend
function requestCheckedCalendars() {

  var chosenNames = getCheckedNames();

  // Submit these names to the backend, to receive their calendar events.
  google.script.run
    .withUserObject(chosenNames)
    .withSuccessHandler(requestCalendarEvents)
    .loopToGetCals(JSON.stringify(chosenNames))
 }
```

An Html template - I created `<a>` elements containing names while was looping script properties:

```js
                 //creating a new <a> tag
                 var newATag = document.createElement("a") 
                 
                 //set a class to a new tag
                 newATag.setAttribute("class", "collection-item");
                 
                 // add the URL attribute
                 newATag.setAttribute("href", "https://www.blah.com");
                 
                  //setting unique IDs
                 newATag.setAttribute("id", "a" + i);
                 
                 // Add names to it
                 var newText = document.createTextNode(name);
                 
                 //append the text with names to the tag
                 newATag.appendChild(newText);
                 
                 //add item to the mother collection element
                 collection.appendChild(newATag);
```

The collection element (where I put my `<a>` elements) is from MaterialixeCss site:

```
 <div class="collection" id = "coll"> 
 </div>   

  //collection element from Materializecss site
   var collection = document.getElementById("coll")
```

Comment: when I pass as .loopToGetCals(); instead of .loopToGetCals(JSON.stringify(chosenNames)) the backend function is being called but the log says that the values of names are undefined.

Comment: This doesn't give the name value either: names[j].childNodes[0].nodeValue

Comment: What should "name" be?  If its the hyperlink then simply var a = document.getElementsByTagName("a"); alert(a[0]);  You don't need Array.from because a is already an array.

Comment: Oh I will look to it. I need text values not links. The text on that links.

Comment: changed but it didn't influence the result so far. I can't get these <a> tags values, instead I get undefined. I got them once and don't know how, I don't remember changing anything. Weird..

Answer (score 0):

## Getting Values from Checkboxes

html fragment:

```
   <br /><input type="checkbox" id="chk1" name="Checks" value="1" /><label for="chk1">One</label>
   <br /><input type="checkbox" id="chk2" name="Checks" value="2" /><label for="chk2">Two</label>
   <br /><input type="checkbox" id="chk3" name="Checks" value="3" /><label for="chk3">Three</label>
   <br /><input type="button" id="chkbtn" value="SaveChecks" onClick="saveChecks();" />
```

JavaScript:

```
function saveChecks() {
    var chA=document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"][name="Checks"]:checked');
    var cbA=[];
    console.log('Checkboxes: %s',JSON.stringify(chA));
    for(var i=0;i<chA.length;i++) {
      console.log('id: %s name: %s value: %s',chA[i].id,chA[i].name,chA[i].value);
      cbA.push({id:chA[i].id,name:chA[i].name,value:chA[i].value});
    }
    google.script.run.displayCheckBoxes(cbA);
  }
```

Some Google Script to display values:

```
function displayCheckBoxes(chA) {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var html='';
  for(var i=0;i<chA.length;i++) {
    html+=Utilities.formatString('<br />id: %s name: %s value: %s', chA[i].id,chA[i].name,chA[i].value);
  }
  var userInterface=HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(userInterface, 'Checked Boxes');
}
```

The Rendered Html:

[image]

The Rendered dialog:

[image]

## Values from anchors

```
function getAnchors() {
      var aA=document.getElementsByTagName("a");
      for(var i=0;i<aA.length;i++) {
        //for(key in aA[i]){console.log('key: %s value: %s',key,aA[i][key]);} //display all possible values
        console.log('href: %s text: %s',aA[i].href, aA[i].text);
      }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for help, but I need to get values from <a> tags not from <input> tags. Checkboxes and <a> tags connected only logically not physically)

Comment: I am desperate. I simplified it and created <span> elements with text content which is perfectly shown in a sidebar. But I can't get span values. Then I put Logger.log at the 2-nd row of a function after this: var spans = document.getElementsByTagName("span")/and this Array.from(document.getElementsByTagName("span")) and no logs found. That's riducilous. How cannot it read even this line, what's wrong?