# Mystery: checkboxes correct array line is not being executed. Where's the bug?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Working with data in Google Sheets.
**I might have done something wrong with checkboxes.**

I have this single checkbox in my html file (from MaterializeCss.com):

```
<label id = "check" >
<input type="checkbox" class="filled-in" checked="checked" />
<span></span>
</label>
```

Then on window.onload() I clone it dynamically in a loop - as many times as many names I get from script properties:

```
 //cloning the original checkbox
 var checkbox = document.getElementById("check").cloneNode(true)
             
 //setting unique IDs
 checkbox.setAttribute("id", "check" + i);
             
 //appending it to the collection element
 collection.appendChild(checkbox);
```

I clone the `<label>` tag and state "true" which should clone all parts that are inside including class I guess.

All this data goes to a sidebar and work fine.

Then I have a button which I assign my function to:

```
 document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click", requestCheckedCalendars)
```

Then I am trying to establish client-server communication and I can't get the data stably - it showed couple of times but mostly not, I don't even get what was changed.

**This simple line is the first line of a function and it is not working**, not being logged, recorded to a cell etc.

```
var allCheckboxes = document.getElementsByClassName('filled-in');
```

What do I do wrong here?

Comment: did you try console logging something to see if the function is actually firing?

Comment: "Then on `window.onload()` I clone it dynamically in a loop" .Make sure you are using `let`(not `var`) in your loop. 2) Where are you calling `getElementsByClassName('filled-in')` in the **global scope**?

Comment: Your check boxes does not have any name attribute or any data attribute that can hold some data except its default attrs and props! the first line of your function makes perfect sense and it is getting all the checkboxes in my case.

Comment: @nick, as I wrote I did, and the very first phrase is not logged.

Comment: @ Maheer Ali I use getElementsByClassName('filled-in') in the function. Why let and not var?

Comment: @Muhammad it's ok that they don't hold data, that's next level) at least I want to resolve checkboxes for now)) You see, the line is correct, then why it is not logged and not being read by code? Perhaps smth is wrong in other places... mistery...

Comment: Your code fragments seem to work fine here: https://jsfiddle.net/fa2qmLgc/

Comment: @tevemadar right, I also see them appeared in my sidebar stably. But when it gets to client-server comm part I don't get values. I am new to all this and don't know where to look: whether I put things in wrong order or it's a framework bugs or else. I don't know what other piece of code to show))

Comment: Here is what I tried on js fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/9y20tpcn/

Comment: Problems have to be reproducible, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve - until then, any help attempt is just wild guessing.

Comment: Guys thank you all, I found one silly mistake: I used Logger.log in Javascript file which is not working there. But moving further I am still stuck with attempts to get text values with my function. Can someone please help me here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55548108/pass-values-of-a-elements-from-client-side-to-a-server-side-function